# How do I write dynamic CDK configurations during deployment?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cdk

I have a simple CDK application with a backend stack that basically creates an gateway API and configures a cognito workflow for user registration and login using google federation.

In addition, there is a frontend stack which creates a ApplicationLoadBalancedFargateService and loads a NextJS application running as a docker image.

There are two interdependent variables that both stacks need and it has become a catch 22 situation.

The backend stack needs the frontends URL, because it needs to configure the **UserPoolClient** callback URL

The frontend stack needs the backends RestApi URL for configuring the NextJS env file specifying the fetch URLs.

[image]

For production deployment, I already know the domain and api URLs ahead of time ie

[www.example.com](http://www.example.com)
api.example.com

so it's not an issue, but for staging and development I rely on the outputted URLs generated by AWS.

How can I grab these values during cdk deployment and what's the best way to do this?
I am thinking of deploying the frontend first to get the URL, and then feed that to the backend stack as part it's callbackUrl.
Then somehow use AppConfig to specify the API url for nextJS to read and use when fetching data. Is this a good approach?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you say, the CDK can't deploy the app if each stack depends upon the other.  One way to remove the cyclic dependency is to add an event-triggered Lambda to the Backend Stack.  The Lambda sets the Callback URL whenever the Frontend Stack deploys.

1. Frontend Stack: Add a Parameter Store [StringParameter](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/api/v2/docs/aws-cdk-lib.aws_ssm.StringParameter.html) construct.  Give it an explicit `parameterName`.  Set its value to the NextJS URL your backend needs for the callback URL.
2. Backend Stack: use a dummy Cognito callbackUrl in your CDK code.  This solves the Catch-22 problem - the app will deploy.
3. Backend Stack: Add an EventBridge rule that [triggers whenever your Frontend Stack deploys](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/stacks-event-bridge.html).
4. Backend Stack: The rule's target is a Lambda function in your Backend Stack.  The Lambda calls two APIs: the Systems Manager [GetParameter](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/systems-manager/latest/APIReference/API_GetParameter.html) API to fetch the Callback URL value and the Cognito [UpdateUserPoolClient](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognito-user-identity-pools/latest/APIReference/API_UpdateUserPoolClient.html) API to update it in Cognito.

To make this work, the Backend Stack just needs to know the Frontend Stack's stack name (for the event rule) and the name of the parameter where the Frontend Stack has stored the callback URL.

---

Note:  Alternatively, it might be possible to add Step 4's Lambda to the Frontend Stack as a Custom Resource.  This would be a pure CloudFormation solution without a need for Step 3's event logic.   The Frontend Stack would need to know the Cognito ClientId.  The big disadvantage woud be that the Frontend Stack would be modifiying a Backend Stack resource, introducing cross-stack mingling of concerns.  The above event-driven solution maintains better separation of concerns.

Comment: so for the backend API, I am assuming first I have to deploy the backend API, fetch the value in CDK and populate a .env file in the frontend code prior to deployment? If so how can that be done?
Run backendStack first, export .env file after deploy then deploy frontend?
Can all of this be automated during a build process?

Comment: @ArmenB I believe the answer's 4 steps are sufficient.  Have you tried it?  I don't understand the questions in the comment, sorry.  If having tried the solution you still have problems, feel free to edit your question, adding more context about your follow-up questions.

Comment: thank you for the answer @fedonev, the steps do actually help in a way that opens up a path of solutions that I never considered before so thanks again.
However, the catch 22 part is not addressed, and that is I have to specify the URL of the backend API in the frontend nextjs env file.
I have also heard most of these initialization configurations can be done during deployment when using AWS CI/CD pipelines. Do you know anything about this? have you used AWS CI/CD pipeline to set configuration parameters during deployment?

Comment: @ArmenB  Glad to help.  I believe you have two unrelated problems:  (1) a cross-stack cyclic dependency (aka "catch-22") and (2) a requirement that Frontend Stack write a Backend Stack output (API URL) to an .env file at deploy-time.  My answer fixes #1.  Problem #2 is not a "catch-22". #2 would need solving even if your app had a single stack.  Yes, you can use AWS CI/CD tools to fix #2.  The CDK can help.  It's enough of a different problem, though, that I think it deserves a separate SO question.  If you do create a new question, be sure to include how your frontend app is hosted.